# How do I get the tooltip background to extend or grow as I input more text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, tooltip

I have a tooltip background-image that looks like this:

[image: tooltip-bg]

My css is like this:

```
p#vtip
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 13.5pt;
    background:url("tooltip-bg.png") no-repeat;
    border: 0px solid #a6c9e2;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 9999;
    height:48px;
    width:140px;
    color:White;
}

p#vtip #vtipArrow
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

This is the jquery code:

```
this.vtip = function() {    
    this.xOffset = -10; // x distance from mouse
    this.yOffset = 10; // y distance from mouse       

    $(".vtip").unbind().hover(    
        function(e) {
            this.t = this.title;
            this.title = ''; 
            this.top = (e.pageY + yOffset); this.left = (e.pageX + xOffset);

            $('body').append( '<p id="vtip"><img id="vtipArrow" />' + this.t + '</p>' );

            $('p#vtip #vtipArrow').attr("src", 'images/vtip_arrow.png');
            $('p#vtip').css("top", this.top+"px").css("left", this.left+"px").fadeIn("slow");

        },
        function() {
            this.title = this.t;
            $("p#vtip").fadeOut("slow").remove();
        }
    ).mousemove(
        function(e) {
            this.top = (e.pageY + yOffset);
            this.left = (e.pageX + xOffset);

            $("p#vtip").css("top", this.top+"px").css("left", this.left+"px");
        }
    );            

};

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    vtip();
})
```

I then apply the css class to the image on my page:

```
<div title="Bike" class="vtip">
<img alt="" class="img1" style="width: 248px; height: 163px;" src="bike.jpg" /><br />
</div>
```

But how do i get the tooltip background to extend or grow as i input more text?

Comment: Do you mean to extend the background-image? It has its own width and height. I don't see a way to do this unless you want to stretch the image.

Comment: @Elaine Marley: Yes extend the tooltip so it gets wider and larger as more text is added. I dont really want to stretch the image.

Comment: well the image is the way it is, if you add more text, you can get the div to grow but not the image.

Comment: What about chopping the tooltip background into start middle and end? would that work?

Comment: What you want is the [sliding doors technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/). The problem with using the image you have is that you can only stretch it horizontally, it'll look horrible stretched vertically. And if you have a lot of content inside the tooltip, your best bet would be using a css gradient background instead of an image as @Elaine said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I could find for you:

- Using the "chopping" approach you suggested: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/csstooltips/
- More examples of tooltips (some are just css and don't use images so you would avoid your current issue): http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/06/12/tooltips-scripts-ajax-javascript-css-dhtml/

I'd go the CSS way if I were you :D

Comment: I know, i would go with the css option too but the design is like this, so i must make it exactly like that.